# How To Publish A 3 Tier MVC Application in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, deployment, 3-tier

I made a mvc webshop where I got the mvc part already deployed. but now I have to deploy my Data layer, Logic layer & Models.

In the picture below you can see my Solution:

[image]

My FileZilla files:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are referenced, they will be published automatically, when you publish the MVC application.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) may give you more detailed information about the whole process.